# d3.js passing parameter into scale domain

Tags: d3.js

Is there any way to pass a parameter into d3.js scale domain?

I want the variable could change to any number base on different if statement. And i don't want to claim other d3.scale.

```
 var x = d3.scaleBand()
         .domain(d3.range(variable))
         .padding(.1)
         .range([0,100]);
```

Comment: Well, you just did! Technically speaking it's an argument, but anyway: what's exactly your question?

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado Sorry for the confusion. What I want is that I can enter a variable in to x scale and domain can change base on that variable. 
Like if I pass a number, 100 , and domain now will be .domain(d3.rang(100))

Comment: You can always pass `d3.range(100)` directly to the `domain()`. Changing the variable, as you described in your comment, will make no difference because the expression `d3.range(variable)` was already evaluated when setting the domain.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado But the variable is not fixed, it could be any number base on different if statement. And i don't want to claim other d3.scale.

Comment: You don't need to. Every time the variable changes just do `scale.domain(d3.range(variable))` again.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado I just figured out how to fix the problem, actually, that was no problem at all, and thank you for your answer.